# Is "ao vivo" locução adjetiva or locução adverbial?

Tags: gramática

Everywhere I've looked it says that it's locução adverbial but in its most common usage is in the phrase "transmissão ao vivo".  If it is modifying the noun transmissão, it's surely an adjective in this case?

Comment: Please try to use proper spelling in your questions.

Comment: Jim Stoke, escrevi em português e em inglês porque não sabia em qual línguas estavas perguntando. O título está em português, mas o texto da pergunta em inglês.

Comment: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

#### English

It can be both. In «A apresentação ao vivo foi ótima», *ao vivo* is an adjective phrase, since it modifies the noun *apresentação*, but in «Transmitimos ao vivo de Brasília.», it is an adverbial phrase, since it modifies the verb *transmitimos*. It is about which it modifies.

#### Português

Depende da frase. Em «A apresentação ao vivo foi ótima», *ao vivo* é uma locução adjetiva, porque modifica o substantivo *apresentação*, mas em «Transmitimos ao vivo de Brasília», *ao vivo* é uma locução adverbial, porque modifica o verbo *transmitimos*.

Comment: Perfect, thank  you! It was just confusing  because every online resource mentioned "ao vivo" as a  locução adverbal only but it makes sense if it can be both.

Comment: @Jimstoke, I believe it is rare for it to be used as an adjective phrase, but it does exist. By the way, was your question in Portuguese or in English?

Comment: @Schilive Você foi falar em transmitir ao vivo,  mas não fazia parte da pergunta. Já é outra pergunta. Sim, funciona como advérbio.

Comment: @Lambie, eu sei, é porque tentei generalizar mais a resposta. Mas, para falar a verdade, eu nem tinha percebido isso.

Comment: @Jim e Shilive, at least here in Portugal *ao vivo* is commonly used adjectivally, and all dictionaries I looked up that have examples include examples of adjectival use, even though none says it is "locução adjetiva".

Comment: @Jacinto Thanks! Thats exactly why I was confused because it is used as an adjective but I only ever saw it described as an adverb.. So I guess its a special case where its an adverb that can be used as an adjecive

Comment: @Jim, don't male too much of it. Only one dictionary (out to the six I looked up) says it is "locução adverbial". It gives definitions and examples of adjectival use ("emissão radiofónica ao vivo", "musica ao vivo") without saying it is "locução adjetiva", and then it says "locução adverbial" and gives parallel definitions and examples ("foi emitido ao vivo", "atuava ... ao vivo"). In the list of abreviations there is none for "locução adjetiva" (but there is for "locução adverbial"), so I reckon this dictionary (Academia das Ciências de Lisboa) doesn't classify anything as "locução adjetiva".

Comment: Schilive, in your first example you're omitting the verb *transmitir*, not *ser* (which is only an auxiliary). And *estar* is a copulative verb, so it can link the subject to an adjective (“estamos prontos”), so in “estamos ao vivo” it is unclear whether *ao vivo* is modifying *estamos* or the implicit *nós*. Same problem with *ser*: it is a copulative verb too (“o show foi ótimo”).

Comment: @Jacinto, you are right. But the *transmitir* could be *ser*, as in *o jogo será amanhã ao vivo*. About the last example, I was thinking it as an adjetctive, but I didn't notice the abiguity. I think the abiguity between adjective and adverb is common between a lot of adverbs, like *perto*.

Comment: Ok, and *o jogo será ao vivo* sounds like adjectival use to me; or do you mean it to be adverbial? I upvoted your answer, but now think it is rather messy. I agree with you that a full answer requires showing that *ao vivo* can be adjectival or adverbial, but why don't you use unambiguous examples, like *a banda X vai atuar ao vivo* and *as atuações ao vivo da banda X são espetaculares*? And I would leave out that omitted verb business; you don't need that to answer the question.

Comment: If you say: Eles transmitiram o jogo ao vivo. ao vivo can be viewed as an adverb. This is just not that hard to get. Come on, now. It is describes how, it's an adverb, if it describes a noun, it's an adjective. Where's the argument?

Comment: @Jacinto, I shall update it. Thanks. A wee bit late, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

**transmissão ao vivo** means: **live broadcast**

as such, *ao vivo* is used adjectivally to describe the kind of broadcast.

transmissão pré-gravada = pre-recorded broadcast.